# What flags should i have to set in clone(2) so that it will work same as pthread_create()?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, clone

I have done a `strace(1)` of `pthread_create(3)`. It indirectly calls the `clone(2)` system call.

And there it will set following flags: (I'm using i386 GNU/Linux (Mint 13))

```
CLONE_VM | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_THREAD | CLONE_SYSVSEM | CLONE_SETTLS | CLONE_PARENT_SETTID | CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID
```

I am good with this all flags. But my question is why does `pthread_create()` set `CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID` flag? According to my knowledge `CLONE_CHILD_SETTID` will set child thread id at location ctid in child memory and `CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID` will erase it while child exits.

(Because there is no `CLONE_CHILD_SETTID` flag set, then why `CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID`?)

Is it really needed? And what are ideal flags should we have to set when we want to achieve functionality of `pthread_create()` using `clone(2)`?

Beginner in this field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you cannot duplicate `pthread_create` using only `clone`. `clone` is written to support library usage, e.g. by pthreads, but on its own it is basically a very customizable thread fork function.

`CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID`, for instance, is designed to support `pthread_join`. What it essentially does is zero the value at `ctid`, then wake up threads that have called a futex_wait on that address. Thus, `pthread_join` can be implemented by simply checking to see if `ctid` is zero (and returning immediately with the status if it is), then doing a futex_wait if necessary (assuming proper synchronization).

Basically, `clone` is an integral part of `pthread_create` but it is not the only part. To support more advanced usage, like essentially everything that pthreads gives you, you will have to write library code on top of `clone` and other calls.